# C# TCP/IP server and client

Tags: c#, tcp

i have a simple TCP client/server application.  How do set up the two program so on the server side it requires a username and a password, and when the client tries to connect, they have to enter the correct user name and password and send it to the server side, the server side will check to see if thats the correct username and password, if its correct then it allows connection, otherwise it rejects the connction

Answer (score 2):

Use WCF since you obviously have not used pure sockets before. It's will most probably be a more stable solution then if you try to learn sockets AND invent your own protocol.

You can use WCF together with the netTcpBinding to achieve what you want. You got a example here: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19314-Client-server-sample-using-WCF-net-tcp-binding.aspx

I'm sorry if this wasn't the answer you where looking for, but there is a lot that need to be implemented correctly to get a hassle free tcp/ip client/server solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can not be done using simple TCP/IP. You'd either have to invent some kind of protocol or use WCF or the like.

As the "connect" happens before anything can be sent, there's no way of sending credentials "along with the connect". You'd have to have the client connect, receive a command for "Login", check credentials and pass back some unique identifier that then needs to be sent along with every command so the server can check whether the client was authenticated. That's how I'd do it if WCF was not an option.

Comment: i have a login control where the user have to type in username and password but the problem is that anyone can just make a program to connect to the specific ip address with the correct port and they will have connection to it.  Thats why i wanted the server side to chck instead before allowing connection

Comment: I know what you're trying to achieve, but this can simply not be done using TCP/IP only without you defining some kind of protocol over TCP/IP. As I said, you could start a "session" on the server for each client (which you'd do anyway to keep the server responsive). If the client is authenticated properly, accept and execute other commands but "Login", otherwise, don't. You can either have the client send a token that you provide after successful login, or have the server "remember" successfully authenticated clients.

Answer (score 0):

White Thorsten is technically correct, I still think there is a solution:

Let the server accept all connections, but then expect as the first data in the connection the username and password. If they are incorrect, the server will then close the connection, and not process any requests that the client may have sent on the connection.

Comment: ***scratchhead*** Isn't that equivalent to what I said, including my above comments?

Comment: Not exactly. The OP is concerned with using unauthorized connections. So pointing out that it is actually username and password (rather than "credentials"), and pointing out that you close the connection when the credentials are incorrect, may be key to understanding. In addition, I fail to see a point in using cookies here.